# How do I call a plugin in an if else in PHP using PyroCMS

Tags: php, pyrocms

example

```
<?php
if ($a > $b) {
    {{ graph:top_coders_one }}
} elseif ($a == $b) {
    {{ graph:daily_commits_two }}
} else {
    {{ graph:commit_stream_two }}
}
?>
```

my plugin function does not work inside the php if/else

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ if a > b }}
  {{ graph:top_coders_one }}
{{ else }}
  {{ graph:top_coders_two }}
{{ endif }}
```

Try that without the `<?php` tags